# FROM keyword not found where expected - ORA-00923

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this simple SQL query which I am trying to run for a uni project. I'm getting the error in the title however I've ran a very similar query with no problem.

```
select booking.customer_id, booking_start_date
   SUM(total_cost) sales
from booking
order by 2 desc
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have missed a `,`  after `booking_start_date`.

Try -

```
select booking.customer_id, 
       booking_start_date,
       SUM(total_cost) sales
from booking
GROUP BY booking.customer_id, booking_start_date
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: I actually tried that previously. It returns ORA-00937: not a single-group group function.

Comment: Yes that is right. You need to add a GROUP BY. try GROUP BY booking.customer_id, booking_start_date

Answer (score 0):

try the following..

```
select 
    booking.customer_id
    , booking.start_date
    , SUM(booking.total_cost) sales
from
    booking
group by
    booking.customer_id
    , booking.start_date
order by 
    2 desc
```

Comment: I assume the column booking_start_date was intended to be booking.start_date

Answer (score 0):

This is your updated query. You should also use GROUP BY when you are using an aggregate  function like COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX etc.

```
select booking.customer_id, booking_start_date
   SUM(total_cost) sales
from booking group by booking.customer_id, booking_start_date
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: When posting code please highlight it and click the `{}` button or press ctrl+k. This indents it by 4 spaces. Your query is incorrect still. You're missing a comma after `booking_start_date`.